Question about Contactor types and wiring between a float switch & well pump?
Can a Siemens 42AF15AF, furnace contactor be used, with a relay,as the connection between a float switch & well pump?

Gosh...I did that every.single.time.Thanks

This is a "definite purpose" contactor, an engineer determined that it was suitable for your furnace.   If you want to use it in some other location according to UL rules you'll need another engineer bless it for that purpose.
Also it needs 120V while your pump probably wants 240, and your relay 24. (I guess)  maybe you can do all that with one transformer but it seems kind of sketchy.

Yeah, definite purpose contactors are UL Recognized (RU mark) = Rather Useless for the OP's application

After picking up the wrong part and realizing how bad it things could've happened, I had to Stop. Regroup. Focus. Decided to see if I can unscrew this pooch instead.

Here's some of the items Im working with:                          VEVOR 1-1/2HP 4" Deep Well Pump 276ft Submersible Pump 37GPM w/Control Box 115V.

GEYA Mini Circuit Breaker AC
MCB GYM8 2P 4.5kA
6/10/16/25/32/40/50/63A Din
Rail

LS MEC GMC-22 Contactor 120V Coil

if you have a new question ask a new question
